# What happens to cookies when there is certificate name mismatch error?

Tags: cookies, ssl-certificate

Cookies with secure flag can not be accessed when the SSL channel is not secure.

What about cookies without the secure flag? Are they sent to server when the certificate doesn't match the domain?

Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are, which is consistent with [RFC 6265 (A. Barth, HTTP State Management Mechanism)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265)